# How can I build an updater for a flask application?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, server

I'm building an internal only flask-based application for work. I would like the program to update automatically from the master branch of my git repository. The application is running on a Linux based (Ubuntu server) VM. Is there a way to get the flask app to automatically pull changes and update from the master branch?

Edit: I don't want a python module updater from pip/git (most common search result)

Update: I found a module called [micropython-ota-updator](https://github.com/rdehuyss/micropython-ota-updater), the problem with this is it seems to update on reboots. The software I'm building is meant to consistently stay up. My inital idea was to check for updates at a interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue:
I decided on dynamically generating GitHub links and building a function for cloning the repo. There were also some configuration files that get saved outside of the repo before cloning. Once the repo is cloned, the configuration files are moved back into their proper places in the new repo. If anyone else wants more information about this, let me know. I'm glad to share my discoveries!